# First timer wants to do it with Mosync

Tags: iphone, android, mobile

I want to learn to develop cross platform mobile/smart phone apps. I would like to go with Mosync because I am a C++ programmer but I am still unsure about some aspects of mosync.

- So can Mosync create apps for IPhone (from looking at the site, its table says it can but its image shows the IPhone grayed out which makes me think that IPhone compatibility is still in development or testing?).
- Can Mosync work with GPS on Android & IPhone platforms?
- Is it easy(not difficult) to compile & run(port) applications to Android & Iphone?
- Are there any drawbacks you have discovered with mosync or any limitations you have discovered with mosync?
- Is it free to develop a commercial app for Iphone & android using mosync? Or do I have to buy Mosyncs subscription to make money off my app?

Comment: I think if you know C++ and are confident with it you shouldn't have a problem doing Java and Objective-C. The problem with these cross-platform mobile frameworks is always that they don't fully support everything. Just a recommendation. Maybe someone else has more experience with this.

Answer (score 2):

MoSync supports iOS, but you will need a Mac with XCode and an Apple Developer account to be able to transfer programs to your iThing.

MoSync supports GPS on all platforms.

It's easier to use MoSync with Android and the other platforms than iPhone, because of the aformentioned reliance on XCode. But it should still be pretty easy, and there are tutorials available to get you started.

MoSync does not yet support every feature available from native SDKs, but it is under constant development. You may use MoSync's Nightly Builds to access the newest features.

MoSync is dual-licensed: GPLv2 and commercial. You may develop closed-source applications with MoSync for free, but you may not actually distribute them before buying a commercial license.

For iPhone, you'll also need to pay for an Apple Developer account.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone works fine, as does Andriod for phones and tabs. What I'm really waiting for is the WP7 version, that would really make my day. I develop on a Mac anyway, using the MacOSX version of the IDE - but making WinPhone apps on a Mac would rule big time!

MoSync is €199 per year, 'bout same as Phonegap. Airplay is $99 but for a iPhone-only version.

Answer (score 0):

This info is a little out dated, here an update.

MoSync is now free for indie developers, the new version is at:
http://www.mosync.com/documentation/manualpages/whats-new-mosync-26-pyramid

I especially love the HTML integration in the new version, the ability to create and call native code, it both directions, cool :) I'm really excited about the potential of HTML UI.

/Tony